# Как реализовать поиск по json?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

Есть json вида :

```
[{
    "id": 242,
    "name": "Abdul Rahman Baba",
    "position": "Left-Back",
    "jerseyNumber": 6,
    "dateOfBirth": "1994-07-02",
    "nationality": "Ghana",
    "contractUntil": "2020-06-30",
    "marketValue": "10,000,000 €"
}, {
    "id": 435,
    "name": "Falcao",
    "position": "Centre Forward",
    "jerseyNumber": 9,
    "dateOfBirth": "1986-02-10",
    "nationality": "Colombia",
    "contractUntil": "2016-06-30",
    "marketValue": "35,000,000 €"
}, {
    "id": 1840,
    "name": "Asmir Begovic",
    "position": "Keeper",
    "jerseyNumber": 1,
    "dateOfBirth": "1987-06-20",
    "nationality": "Bosnia-Herzegovina",
    "contractUntil": "2019-06-30",
    "marketValue": "12,000,000 €"
}]
```

Как можно и реализовать поиск по такому json с выводом результатов ? Возможно есть какие фрейм-ворки?

То-есть интересует если пользователь наберет в инпут: 12,000,000 € Чтоб вывело всех футболистов с таким гонораром, или например введет введет гонорар не до конца например так 12 тогда по частичному совпадению(всех футболистов в которых встречается в гонораре либо дате рождения число 12), или введет Ghana тогда выведутся все футболисты которые из Ганы, или если введут частично например так: Gh , то выводятся все футболисты в в описании которых есть GH.

Есть ли фрейм-ворки для такого ? И стоит ли их использовать или можно как-то проще решить данную проблему ?

Comment: [Array.prototype.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для фильтрации массивов можно использовать функцию [Array.prototype.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

Для фильтрации по конкретному полю

```
var search = "text"
var result = arr.filter(function(el){
    return el.fieldName.indexOf(search) > -1;//fieldName - поле по которому нужно фильтровать
});
```

Если искать нужно сразу по всем полям, то функцию фильтра можно модифицировать, например, так

```
var search = "text"
var result = arr.filter(function(el){
    for(var field in el){
        if(el[field].indexOf(search) > -1){
            return true;//если нашли хотя бы одно поле содержащее искомую строку, оставляем объект
        }
    }
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Думаю стоит добавить, что массив из json делается JSON.parse

Comment: @Mike, я уверен на 99%, что здесь под _JSON_ имеют ввиду обычный массив.